# Can I upload an image as attachment with Slack API?

Tags: php, laravel, slack-api

I have integrated *Slack* API using *cURL* in my project.
I want to send an image as my attachment. It works while sending full image path in `image_url`. But when I convert that image to *base64* string and then pass it with `image_url` it doesn't go as attachment.

So basically I want to post *base64* string as my image attachment. Because I don't want to store the image on my server.

```
{"attachments":
    [
        {
            "fallback": "Required text summary of the attachment that is shown by clients that understand attachments but choose not to show them.",
            "image_url":"",
            "text":"",
            "color":"#7CD197"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not `save->send->delete`?

Comment: @ThomasMoors that won't work. the moment you delete the image on your server also Slack will not show it any longer

Comment: @ErikKalkoken If you send it as an attachment that would not be true? Like if you send it from your PC

Comment: I think you mean image uploads, that is different from attachments. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

You can not submit a full image as attachments, only URLs to an image.

If you want to upload an image to Slack you can do so by using [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). Here is a curl example for uploading a GIF image from the Slack documentation:

```
curl -F file=@dramacat.gif -F channels=C024BE91L,#general -F token=xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

An alternative is to use an image hoster (e.g. http://imgur.com) to upload and store your image (through their API). Then you can include the image URL in your attachment.

I personally prefer the second option, since its more flexible to include image URLs in messages and images then do not reduce your precious storage space on Slack.

Comment: @Sarvarnabi Khan if this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution. So that this question can be closed. Thank you!