# How to upload Google Spreadsheet chart to Slack channel

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack-api

I am writing an app script for my Google Spreadsheet and I am wondering how to send charts as an image attachment to Slack?

This is the function for getting the chart:

```
function getChart(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var pic = chart.getAs('image/png');
  if (chart){
    msg(pic);
    return pic;
  }
}
```

And this is my "dashbot" function which sends a text message to slack:

```
function dashbot() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var content = {"channel": "XXX", //edit
                 "username": "XXX",
                 "text": "XXX"};
  var params = {
     "method": "post",
     "payload": JSON.stringify(content)
   };
   UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://hooks.slack.com/XXXXX', params)
}
```

Any ideas how to get forward on that?

Comment: Here is how you can upload images to Slack https://stackoverflow.com/a/45999393/4379151

Comment: If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 5):

How about this sample script? Files cannot be directly uploaded to Slack using the Webhook as @Erik Kalkoken said. So when files are uploaded to Slack, URL has to be used. After the file was uploaded using URL, even if the file was removed, the file on Slack is not removed. I prepared a sample script reflected this.

The flow of script is as follows.

#### Flow :

1. Get a chart
2. Convert the chart to an image blob as png
3. Save the image blob as a file
4. Modify the file permission to the open
5. Retrieve URL for the file
6. Post the payload with the URL
7. Modify the file permission to the close

In this script, the uloaded file is in root directory on Google Drive. Even if the file was removed, the file on Slack is not removed.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  if (chart) {
    var pic = chart.getAs('image/png');
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(pic).setName("sampleimage.png");
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); // Modify file permission to the open.
    var content = {
      "channel":"XXX",
      "username":"XXX",
      "text":"XXX",
      "attachments":[{"image_url": "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId()}]
    };
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://hooks.slack.com/XXXXX",
      {
        method: "post",
        payload: JSON.stringify(content),
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
      }).getContentText();
    Utilities.sleep(3000); // Wait for until reading image file from Slack.
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.NONE); // Modify file permission to the close.
  }
}
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.